# How to get colorgradient using ColorRamp in R?

Tags: r, color-palette

In R I want to color points according to some values between 0 and 1. Why does the following minimal code generate a plot with a bunch of random colors? And why not a smooth transition from white to dark blue?

code needs add-on package rcolorbrewer:

```
niceblues <- brewer.pal(5, "Blues")
blues <- colorRamp(niceblues)
plot(0:10, 0:10, pch=21, bg=blues((0:10)/10))
```

Comment: Your minimal working example is too minimal... Educated guess: "R"?

Comment: I think you want `col=` instead of `bg`. however, you are passing a matrix to the `plot` command and only the first column is used as the colour instead of the full `rgb` matrix. So you can try `rgbColours = blues(0:10/10) ; cols = apply(rgbColours/255, 1, function(x) rgb(x[1], x[2], x[3]))` to get the colours then `plot(0:10, 0:10, pch=16, cex=2, col=cols)` (as an alt you can try `plot(0:10, 0:10, pch=16, cex=2, col=colorRampPalette(niceblues)(11))`)